# How Do I Change The RMI Listen Backlog Size?

Tags: java, linux, rmi

I am having network issues with my Java (7) application on linux where packets are occasionally delayed.

The sysadmins have said that the listen backlog set is too low and thus is not accepting connections fast enough.

```
ss -lt
State      Recv-Q Send-Q    Local Address:Port    Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      50        *:1099                *:*
```

The default on this system is 128

```
sysctl -a 2>/dev/null|grep net.core.somaxconn
net.core.somaxconn = 128
```

Is 50 the default for RMI connections in JDK7?

How do I increase it to make it use the system default?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html

Comment: Your sysadmins are mistaken. RMI doesn't set its own backlog, it uses the default, and accepts connections as fast as possible. 'Packets delayed' doesn't have anything do with listen backlog. If backlog was the problem you would have connect failures, not delayed packets. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: This statement is not true. RMI does in fact set the backlog and doesn't use the system default.

Comment: @opticyclic RMI sets it where? Your answer indicates that `new ServerSocket()` sets it, not RMI.

Comment: @OP 50 has been the default backlg for *all* `ServerSockets` in the JDK since at least 1.1.2. This has always been a terrible mistake. They should have always used 0 and let the system assert its own default. However I still doubt that this has anything to do with your packet delay problem.

Comment: So what if it has nothing to do with my packet delay problem? The questions asked are: Is 50 the the default for RMI connections in JDK7? and How do I increase it to make it use the system default. Don't downvote because you have other questions in your head!

Comment: @user207421 Stop splitting hairs. The default RMI implementation calls another class that sets a default value. Ergo the default RMI implementation is 50. Why are you bogging this question down with your useless comments?

Comment: @opticyclic Because you falsely accused me of making a false statement. I didn't. I chose my words carefully and they are all correct.

Comment: Lets move these comments to chat as they aren't helping the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 50 **is** the default value in the JDK.

`sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint` calls `RMIServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(this.listenPort);`
The implementations of `RMIServerSocketFactory` e.g. `RMIDirectSocketFactory` do 
`new ServerSocket(int);`

As we can see from the ServerSocket javadocs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)

> The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a
>   request to connect) is set to 50

Therefore, one way to increase the value is to create your own implementation of `RMIServerSocketFactory` and call a different `ServerSocket` constructor that allows you to set your own backlog value.